# Unit testing angular intercept

Tags: angularjs, intercept, unit-testing

Is this even possible?

I can mock $httpBackend, and the intercept is called during $httpBackend.flush(); but I cannot get hold of it. So my intercept function changes the state of $rootScope, but even that does not help, because it does so both on request and on response -- and all I get is the state after response.

Is there a way to check the state of $rootScope after request? Is there a way to check the state of config, which is the input parameter?

Here is the code:

```
// application
//
angular.module('myApp',[]);
//
// controller
//
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, _$http_) {
    var $http = _$http_;
    $scope.onSubmit = function() {
        var config = {method: 'post', url: '/foo.py', data: 'bar', myProp: 'request'};
        $http(config).success(function(result) {
        }).error(function(data) {
            $scope.error = data;
        });
    };
}]);
//
// service
//
var fooService = angular.module('FooService', ['ngResource']);

fooService.factory('FooIntercept', function ($q, $window, $log, $rootScope) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            $rootScope.myProp = config.myProp;
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Session ' + $window.sessionStorage.sessionId;
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if($rootScope.myProp) {
                $rootScope.myProp = 'response';
            }
            return response;
        },
        responseError : function(response) {
            if($rootScope.myProp) {
                $rootScope.myProp = 'error';
            }

            var errorMessage = response.config.errorMessage;
            if(errorMessage) {
                $window.alert(errorMessage);
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});

fooService.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('FooIntercept');
});
//
// test
//
describe('trying to mock httpBackend', function() {
    var $controller;
    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(module('FooService'));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('not so simple...', function() {
        var ctrl = $controller('FooCtrl', {'$scope':$rootScope});
        expect($rootScope.onSubmit).toBeDefined();
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('/foo.py', 'bar').respond({UserName: 'Fred', serverAddress: 'foo'});
        $rootScope.onSubmit();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($rootScope.myProp).toBe('request');
    });
});
```

Comment: an interceptor is like any other Angular factory, so you can test it in the same way. Don't bother mocking $http responses. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27117785/2943490

Comment: @user2943490 Thank you very much, that link is just what I needed to see the light!